# String to Date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, date

I have many many string values that look like this "Mar 31, 1999".

Is there an easy way to get this string format to a Ruby Date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `Date.parse` method :

```
> Date.parse "Mar 31, 1999"
=> Wed, 31 Mar 1999
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Date.parse`. For more complex date strings you may use [`strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime):

```
require 'date'
puts Date.strptime('Mar 31, 1999', '%b %d, %Y') #->1999-03-31
```

`strptime` is kind of a reverse [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime)

Answer (score 0):

For parsing a wide range of date strings, check out [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic)