# How to convert %Y%m%d%H%m%s to YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and have dates with the format 
`20170802173300` witch is:

```
Mie, 02 Ago 2017 17:33:00 -0300.
```

How can I convert this to ?

```
2017-08-02 17:33:00 -0300
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727898/parsing-string-dates-in-ruby-such-as-28-may-10/9728030#9728030 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511141/string-to-date-in-ruby/14511436#14511436. Your code would be `DateTime.strptime('20170802173300','%Y%m%d%H%M%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'date'
date = '20170802173300'
formatted_date = DateTime.parse(date).to_s
# => "2017-08-02T17:33:00+00:00"

# and to be more explicit:
really_formated_date = DateTime.parse(date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
# => "2017-08-02 17:33:00 +00:00"
```

Comment: That works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strftime`:

```
datetime = 'Mie, 02 Ago 2017 17:33:00 -0300'
datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S %z')
# => 2017-08-02 17:33:00
```

Comment: minutes should be changed to %M

Answer (score 2):

You can format time anyway you like, in Ruby with [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime).

For format you want it'll be like this:

`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z`

For example: `Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')`

Answer (score -1):

Date now = new Date();
                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand, You are using a Rails method?

Comment: You answer isn't in Ruby

Comment: Sorry for my uncleared answer